# Set author per repository

Tags: magit, git, project

I work on both work and personal projects on my machine, and for my work projects, I prefer to use my work email, and vice versa.

In shell, I use [direnv](http://direnv.net/) to set `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` and `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`.

How do I achieve something like this in magit?

Comment: Might be possible to use `.dir-locals.el` somehow, either modify `process-environment` or `magit-git-global-arguments`.

Comment: i wrote https://github.com/wbolster/emacs-direnv to integrate direnv with emacs. but see my other answer, there are better options for your specific use case here.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do this is to set the author configuration in `.git/config` in each repository, in the same format as in `~/.gitconfig`, i.e.:

```
[user]
    name = My Name
    email = me@example.com
```

Comment: Hmm... The problem with this approach, is that I need to do this in each repo, and I have a lot of work repos. With direnv, I can set this up in the folder that contains all the repos, and it works. Wondering if there is something similar I can do.

Answer (score 7):

you can do this with one-time git configuration. you can use it for `email` and so on, but also for using a different `ssh` key:

in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
path = .gitconfig_work
```

in `~/.gitconfig_work`:

```
[user]
email = …

[core]
sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_…_work -o 'IdentitiesOnly yes'
```

explanation: this makes git use another configuration, which specifies `email` and a ssh key (which you should create with a different filename and then add to your github account) when running git anywhere below the `~/work` directory. in practice, this one time configuration makes it work for all current and future clones.

Answer (score 4):

Anoter useful option is the [git-identity package](https://github.com/akirak/git-identity.el).

From its README:

> This Emacs package lets you manage local Git identities, i.e.
>   user.name and user.email options in .git/config, inside Emacs. It can
>   be useful if you satisfy all of the following conditions:
>
> ```
> - You have multiple Git identities on the same machine(s).
> - You use Emacs.
> - You (almost always) use magit for Git operations on your machine(s).
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Same effective answer as @legoscia, but instead of modifying the file, I find that if you do

```
git config user.email me@example.com
git config user.name "My Name"
```

It sets the local config, i.e `.git/config`

If you add the flag `--global` then it modifies your global config.

Thus you can have different name/email setup per repository, and can even check them by running `git config user.email`. When called without any arguements, it works as a `GET` command.

Comment: Added a comment to @legoscia's answer. Same applies here.

Comment: @zsquare This only needs to be done once, Not sure if there is a parent folder customizability, but it cant be hard to script it into every child of a parent folder

Comment: @zsquare perhaps you can look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42785/can-git-configuration-be-set-across-multiple-repositories and specifically the last answer.